# PHP: Replace Url Character in array

Tags: php, arrays, url

I have a php file to retrieve image file name. the code is like this

```
<?php
$files = array();

$dir = opendir('upload/');

while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    $data = array("picture"=>"http://my IP server/evie/upload/".$file);
    $fil[] = $data;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
$files = array("image"=>$fil);
echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

when I run the code, it look like this

```
{"image":[{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/bangladesh.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/IMG_20130921_074201.jpg"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/afghanistan.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/india.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/china.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/srilanka.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/nepal.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/skorea.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/Honoka-Miki2-300.jpg"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/japan.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/nkorea.png"},{"picture":"http:\/\/my IP server\/evie\/upload\/pakistan.png"}]}
```

It has a backslash '\'. how to replace it?
I want the url look like a valid url. anyone can help me?

Comment: Your example output does not include the backslash, where are you having the problem?  If it is with $file patching you could just str_replace \\ with /.

Comment: @Scott'scm6079' thank's for your answer. can you check this url https://www.flickr.com/photos/133076409@N07/18364878028/ when I run my code, it's look like that photo in url. please help me

Answer (score 1):

No problem here. json escapes slashes. If you do reverse operation - json_decode, you will see one slash

```
[0]=>
array(1) {
  ["picture"]=>
  string(44) "http://my IP server/evie/upload/bangladesh.png"
}
```

Comment: thank's for your answer, I am little bit understand. So I must use json_decode to replace the backslash? did you see my picture at flickr.com/photos/133076409@N07/18364878028 whether my code is correct?

Comment: You don't need to remove them. You produce correct json with escaped spashes. What is a problem?